# My microphone doesn't work unless i manually shift the jack around and place it in a certain way

Tags: audio-hardware

What are the possible causes and waht can i do to fix it?

It starts working whenever i apply some pressure to it to force the jack to one side but otherwise it doesn't.

Please advise, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This will be one of two things;

- A dodgy cable connection in the microphone cable or plug - you can confirm this is the case by using an *alternative* microphone and see if the problem still occurs. If it does;
- A dodgy connection inside the microphone socket - this will require either some handy DIY to fix it (I am not recommending that you do this) or a replacement of whatever soundcard or motherboard the socket is connected to.

Based on your description of the problem I would believe that it is the latter, but it's worth testing the first anyway since this is the easier and cheaper option to replace in the event it is at fault.

Comment: Oh i've tried the first... Yeah other mics have the same issue. If i purchase a steelseries 5h which has it's own usb sound card, would that fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, that would act as its own 'soundcard' and the connection would be via USB rather than using the microphone socket so this would work around the issue.